# Cannot run non-root docker container with GPU

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I made a fresh install of docker desktop from official docs [docker desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/).

Then I installed NVIDIA Container Toolkit following official docs [nvidia container toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html).

When I run docker with non-root permission:

```
docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.6.2-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi
```

It gave the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

The error was **not happened** if I use **sudo permission**. Also, it is fine if I run a non-gpu container (without --gpu all option).

Some information about my PC:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Nvida driver: 525, CUDA version: 12.0
- Docker desktop: 23.0.5

I have tried several suggestions:

- Add user to docker group, and video group
- Install nvidia-docker2
- Try changing ldconfig path: [change ldconfig](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1163#issuecomment-570945834)
- Change GPU permissions:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/nvidia*
sudo chmod 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm*
```

- Set permission for libnvidia-ml.so.1

```
sudo chown root:video /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libnvidia-ml.so.1
sudo chmod 664 /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libnvidia-ml.so.1
```

- And some other methods which I will continue listing when I remember.

I am really desperate now. Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying countless methods, I came across this post: [docker desktop problem](https://forums.docker.com/t/nvidia-cuda-doesnt-work-on-docker-desktop-but-works-on-docker-engine/130668).

As pointed out in the post, this is an unsolved problem of Docker Desktop. So I switched to Docker Engine only, and I could use GPU normally without any difficulties.

While waiting for the fix of Docker Desktop, I think Docker Engine is more than enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu/Linux and Docker Desktop. Have the same situation. Workaround is to use a docker default context `docker context use default` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but it can be useful to others.

I solved the problem by reinstalling docker, but after every reboot, I had the same problem again with `libnvidia-ml.so.1`.
After trying several methods, I realized a version mismatch between docker client and server after the reboots (you can get this info with `docker version` command).

In my case, snap (which I didn't use for anything) was restoring a snapshot in every reboot. Deleting docker from snap and reinstalling it following [the official manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) solved the issue.

Check what is under snap with `snap list`.

You can use this command to uninstall docker from snap and delete the snapshot: `sudo snap remove docker --purge`.